# Filter Custom Grid Collection

Tags: magento2, collection, grid

I am trying to filter my collection from my custom table using `_initSelect` method in class `Collection` in namespace Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\MyData

```
protected function _initSelect()
    {
        // code for filtering collection
    }
```

But it is not going through this method.

Am I following the correct approach?
What can I filter my collection to show data in Grid in admin?

Comment: How to do that ....this filter

Comment: @PriyaM Didn't get your question.

Comment: If u know that ...Please explain me..How to customise grid collection

Comment: @PriyaM Share your code

Comment: Model, ResourceModel, di, layout, ui_component file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of the type in `virtualType` tag in di.xml
Changed

```
<virtualType name="Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\MyData\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
```

to

```
<virtualType name="Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\MyData\Grid\Collection">
```

Also Changed

`class Collection extends \Anshu\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\MyData\Collection implements \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface`

to

```
class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below function to filter collection in grid

```
protected function _prepareCollection(){
}
```

Comment: I have tried this method as well, but it is also not working.